# Null Hypothesis for t-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have read articles/books in which the null hypothesis for the t-test is sometimes phrased as the sample means being from the same population. However, if the two groups you are comparing are clearly not the same (e.g., male vs. female), then why is it phrased that they are from the same population?

Comment: If the distributions were actually identical (they won't be in practice, but for the two sample t-test with equal variances and with the assumption of normality, that's the case under the null of equal means), then *on that variable you're looking at* you can treat them as one population with arbitrary group-labels (in the sense that if you shuffled the group labels around, the distributions would not change).

Answer (score 1):

The null hypothesis says that two random variables have the same expected value.

All the narration about populations and samples is just a metaphor used for didactical purposes and it has a lot of blind spots. However, consider the assumptions of t-test: the same variance, and the normal distribution. If the null hypothesis is true, there is no difference between the distributions (normal distribution is fully specified with spread and location). So you can say that your observations (numbers) are drawn from the exactly same population (of numbers). Nevertheless, if you want to talk about populations of people, I would prefer to verbalize the hypothesis that two populations have the same (population) mean.